# If product is in sub-category show code

Tags: terms, children

This code works with categories but not with child sub-categories.

How can I make it work a child category that is not in the url (slug)?

```
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

if ( in_array( 'lucha', $categories ) ) {
  echo '<div class="nota-categorias-especiales">Important: this product has special conditions.

<button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit">Contact Us</button>

 </div>  ';

  } else {}
?>
```

Comment: I have removed the woocommerce tag and the name from the title as this is a general wordpress question and the woocommerce tag is irrelevant. Woocommerce questions are off topic here btw :-). Please feel free to read [ask] and take a [tour] to see how the site operates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just make use of [`has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) which will check if the specific post belongs to the term given

You can do something like this (*Edit: Add post ID if this is used in a function*)

```
global $post;
if(has_term( 'lucha', 'product_cat', $post->ID )) {
    //do something if post has lucha term
}else{
    //do something else if the post don't have lucha term
}
```

Comment: hi pieter I will try it, should I remove the previous lines? I have tried with this code but breaks the page...

Comment: You can remove the code that you have. Just remember, you are going to mix php with html here, and I suspect that is why you get that white page. Remember to use opening and closing php tags when moving to and from php and html

Comment: thanks for yout help pieter, I have tried: with this code but still gives a blank page.... i share:

Comment: `<?php if(has_term( 'lucha', 'product_cat' )) {
  echo '<div class="nota-categorias-especiales">Importante: para comprar productos de tipo Sustratos debes usar un formulario de Pedidos Especial.

<button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit">Hacer un pedido</button>

 </div>  ';
  } else {}

?>
`

Comment: Turn debug on. You have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Just one thing, in your OP you don't have an opening php but in the comment code you have. Also don't post code in the comment section, rather file an edit to your question and add it in there

Comment: sorry for posting code in comments, will never do it again. i have tried and tried doesnt seem to work and breaks the code even if I only use the line of code you sent without html

Comment: You are missing something somewhere. What debug errors do you get. Have you removed **all** the code that you posted in your question

Comment: Fixed the issue, somehow this code works only with categories, but not with child sub-categories of woocommerce products... i dont know how to check sub-category and then do something... i have tried the code with a category and works.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. `lucha` is a parent term in the `product_cat` taxonomy. Under `lucha` you have child terms, and these are the one you want to check. Am I correct.

Comment: I have a category for example lets call it 'Main'. A child category of main is 'Lucha'. Im trying to affect only products that have Lucha as category.

Comment: You have to be specific here. Where exactly are you using this code. What is the real name of your taxonomy. My code exactly does what you want, only targeting the `lucha` term posts. It is either that the taxonomy name is wrong, or you using this code in function which in any case you will need to set the post ID

Comment: Im using this code in my theme's template files, this document is the one that displays the product and it's price. for this certain category, I need to hide the add to cart button (i do it via CSS) and add a custom button that links to a contact form. I can show you how I made it work with a category: http://www.codeshare.io/U9cJq but for some reason this code doesnt work with sub-categories. my subcategory slug is 'lucha' and it's full name 'Lucha Biologia'

Comment: It has to work. This code does not rely on whether a term is a parent term or child term. Again, as I said and asked, under which taxonomy is this term, as it seems like this term does not belong to the `product_cat` taxonomy. This is the only parameter that can make the code fail, and a spelling mistake

Comment: well, in woocommerce  when I edit the category 'Lucha biologica' i can see this in the browser the taxonomy is product_cat

Comment: `Lucha biologica` is the exact name. What is the slug of this term

Comment: the slug is Lucha